# Where can I watch live commentary and live matches between Grandmasters?

Tags: grandmaster, online

I want to watch live matches between GMs. In India here are no TV channels that provide me these matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chess24](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments) has a lot of live transmissions of tournaments. Often even with live commentary and always with computer evaluations (though those can be turned off).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes [Lichess](http://lichess.org) hosts events. They also usually have links on the homepage to Twitch streamers varying in rating.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes [twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Chess) hosts the live games for some tournaments. Depending on which tourney is streaming, the commentary can be particularly good.

Comment: I've been watching Amazingoid on twitch for years. He's got great commentary and interacts a lot with viewers. Always a good show!

Answer (score 2):

The youtube channel for the Chess Club and Scholastic Center of Saint Louis had some pretty enjoyable, interesting, and informative coverage of the [Grand Chess Tour - 2015 Sinquefield Cup](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVWaFpMwtaGiAfweILM7b7IQtIc0L8UHc)  last week. They also have some similar coverage posted from a few previous tournaments, but I mostly go there for the lectures.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes watch on [ChessBomb](http://www.chessbomb.com). It is only the games, no video. The games are analysed with stockfish (or other engine) and sometimes by a GM. Also there is commentary by members.